# Why This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Tags: php, mysql

When running this query i get the following error which i don't understand. I have now join rows, is there some kind of limitation i should know about or am i missing simple error? This is the error:

```
#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

and this is the query i am trying to run:

```
 SELECT t.* 
FROM tasks t 
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.user_id = 1 
WHERE task_id = '677' 

AND createdby IN(
    (SELECT u1.user_id FROM users u1 WHERE u1.user_team = u.user_team 
     AND taskrspnsble IN(
        (SELECT u2.user_id FROM users u2 WHERE u2.user_role <= u.user_role)
    ))
)
```

Comment: Read this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-restrictions.html)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out thanks to the answer of Saty:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM tasks t 
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.user_id = 1 
WHERE task_id = '677' 

AND createdby IN(
    (SELECT u1.user_id FROM users u1 WHERE u1.user_team = u.user_team 
     AND taskrspnsble IN(
        (SELECT u2.user_id FROM users u2 WHERE u2.user_role <= u.user_role)
    ))
)
```